# Can't get DOM element styles

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to loop over some dom elements and get their color, then apply it to another element, but when I do that nothing happens and when I try to console log the property I'm getting it returns nothing. Here's my code:

```js
var btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
var div = document.querySelector('div');

for(i = 0; i < btn.length; i++){
  btn[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    var col = this.style.backgroundColor;
    console.log(col)
    div.style.backgroundColor = col;
  })
}
```

```css
button:nth-of-type(1){
  background-color:red;
}
button:nth-of-type(2){
  background-color:gold;
}
button:nth-of-type(3){
  background-color:teal;
}
div{
  background-color:lightgrey;
  margin:50px;
}
button, div{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
  <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `HTMLElement.style.prop` retrieves the inline stlye; what is found in `style` attribute. You would require to use `Window.getComputedStyle`

```js
var btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
var div = document.querySelector('div');

for(i = 0; i < btn.length; i++){
  
  btn[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
   
    var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(this);
    
    div.style.backgroundColor = computedStyle.backgroundColor;
  
  })

}
```

```css
button:nth-of-type(1){
  background-color:red;
}
button:nth-of-type(2){
  background-color:gold;
}
button:nth-of-type(3){
  background-color:teal;
}
div{
  background-color:lightgrey;
  margin:50px;
}
button, div{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
  <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```